# TFS 2015 - Custom Path Policy Implementation?

Tags: tfs

We have code that we want to be excluded from our Check-In policy that runs a custom code analysis rule set through our on-prem TFS server. We need to install the TFS Power Tools to implement the Custom Path Policy.

The problem is, we have a large number of non .Net developers using our same area for checking in code (i.e. DB developers, QA Engineers) and would like to exclude their code from our check-in policy (it doesn't apply). The only way we can find to do this is through the custom path settings which means they all have to install the Power Tools on their local machines as well.

Is there any other way other than moving the code to another area or having them install the Power tools to exclude their code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a better way to achieve that except the two ways you mentioned.

Theoretically speaking, the policy in TFS server side can achieve that. Please refer to below link and check if that helpful.

http://almsports.net/tfs-server-side-check-in-policy-for-git-repositories/1025/

You can also reference the related thread: [Restricting TFS check-in policy to specific users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900422/restricting-tfs-check-in-policy-to-specific-users)

Comment: First link is dead